# How to select one point per raster grid cell?

Tags: r, sample, r-raster

I have a point shapefile ("search_effort.shp") that is highly clustered and an NDVI raster (resolution in m: 30.94948, 30.77829).  I would like to subset my search_effort.shp by selecting 1 point per raster grid cell and create a new search_effort shapefile. I am using R version 4.0.3

I think I could have used Package ‘gridsample’ (in 'raster' v1.3-1), but it was removed from the CRAN repository and I would prefer not to use the archived version. Is there another way to do this in R?

I have also tried sample.grid but I do not know how to specify my raster as the grid, and have tried the following:

```
# NDVI raster to be used as the reference extent
NDVI_extent <-readGDAL('C:/Model_layers/NDVI.tif')

# Load the file names  
layername <- "SearchEffort"

# Read in the shapefile
search_effort <- readOGR(dsn= ".", layer = layername)
plot(search_effort)

# Set the reference extent
r <- raster(NDVI_extent)

# Extract coordinates from the shapefile
search_effort@coords <- search_effort@coords[, 1:2]

#Subset points
sample.grid(search_effort, cell.size = c(30.94948, 30.77829), n = 1)
```

I get the following error:
"Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “GridTopology” object: cellsize has incorrect dimension."
I get the same error regardless of the cell.size I specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(res=30)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
x <- runif(1000,-180,180)
y <- runif(1000,-90,90)
xy <- cbind(x, y)
```

Solution

```
library(dismo)
s <- gridSample(xy, r, n=1)
```

Illustration

```
plot(as(r, "SpatialPolygons"))
points(s, col="red")
points(xy, cex=.1, col="blue")
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it will work, but I am running into the following error: Error in ss[1:min(n, nrow(ss)), 1:2] : subscript out of bounds Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: I answered my own question - I need to eliminate the 3rd dimension from the SPDF:  
search_effort@coords <- search_effort@coords[, 1:2]

Comment: It is better not to use `@` but, in this case `coordinates(search_effort)`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time and help!